# Html file content inside an object value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Could you please tell me how can I reference an HTML file as a content for my description instead of a string (as seen in the code below) for Angular / Ionic ?
I want to have:

1. `items[0].description` to have content from angular.html
2. `items[1].description` to have content from css.html

Please help me out! Thanks in advance!

```
export class BasicPage {

 items = [];

 constructor(public nav: NavController) {
   this.items = [
    {
    'title': 'Angular',
    'icon': 'angular',
    'description': 'A powerful Javascript framework for building single page apps. Angular is open source, and maintained by Google.',
    'color': '#E63135'
    },
    {
    'title': 'CSS3',
    'icon': 'css3',
    'description': 'The latest version of cascading stylesheets - the styling language of the web!',
    'color': '#0CA9EA'
    }
  ];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a separate function (e.g. getHTMLFile() ) to return html content. To get the html content make a http call to your html file

`http.get("/yout_html_file_path").map((html:string) => this.template = html`

and call this function from your description for each item and use JSON.stringify() to stringify the output returned from this function.

```
this.items = [
    {
    'title': 'Angular',
    'icon': 'angular',
    'description': JSON.stringify(getHTMLFile()),
    'color': '#E63135'
    }
```